# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). And even though I made a sample ad for you guys with the rest of the sample ads, somehow the thread itself didn't get posted. Weird how that works. Anyway, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- relevant blogs and websites about computer science
- computer science, events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if using high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px (2px for high DPI) border surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1195).

Comment: Question: why are the borders not provided/enforced by the style CSS? That way, the borders could pick up the colors of the design. Also, are the borders a requirement for transparent backgrounds as well?

Comment: Yes, borders are required if it's transparent because that ultimately results in a white background (since the site background is white). Not sure what you mean about the first bit though - adapting the CSS to the design of each individual ad?

Comment: Not what I meant. The border could have the/a highlight color from the *site* theme. (As it is, every ad can have a border of a different color!)

Comment: @Raphael Ah. Sometimes the border is itself part of the ad design. For example, the arXiv.org ad below has a multicolor border as appropriate for its own design. Wouldn't look as good if we just had a generic border from the site itself. Likewise with any ad that isn't plain white, once you get to colorful stuff, gotta have the borders (if even any) match appropriately to the colors.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: Copied from [tex.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6493/3213). I think this one is helpful; it can be hard to quickly find the right symbol to use with MathJax.

Comment: As the author of it, I would like to add [write-math.com](http://write-math.com). It is faster, has also the unicode-symbol for copy-and-pasting and a text search. However, it can only recognize 370 symbols by writing (but those symbols are recognized very well).

Comment: I use it often and could not live without it! Thanks to the people who made it possible!

Answer (score 16):

[image: arXiv.org]

Comment: Copied from [math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22427/3330). I think arXiv is (or should be) an ubiquitous reference.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Copied from [math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22441/3330).

Comment: @EvilJS These ads will show on [cs.SE], so there should be ads for CSists. Ads *for* [cs.SE] will have to be posted elsewhere. Anyway, many of our users are in academia, so I figured pointing them towards [academia.SE] may be a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Computer Science Chat]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: This uses the old logo. It needs to be changed.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC [Like so](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1332/98)?

Answer (score 8):

[image: CS stackexchange chat room]

Comment: 1) I don't see how coding represents any aspect of [cs.SE]. 2) It's not clear to me what the graphic has to do with [chat].

Comment: lol R your _criticism_ is entirely predictable. you ask for submissions in chat and then reject a decent one that took time/ effort (kind of a _theme_ on this and other SE sites it seems). will discuss the _meaning_ in chat for anyone who inquires.

Comment: @VZN good luck man just saw it, you may want to check this also (http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02428/alan-turing_2428157b.jpg)

Comment: ***thx all very much for the votes hitting +6 as of now.*** followup/ revealed: the picture is a not-well-known Turing statue with an [Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) at [Bletchley Park](http://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/artblog/2007/jun/19/theenigmaofalanturing). the ad is not meant to _evoke all of CS_ (long/ complex!) or even be very direct about its purpose, instead meant to provoke curiosity. some _(famous! effective!)_ ads from marketing are like this! also a ref to Turings very [_applied side_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2084970/) now overlooked by some.

Comment: This now appears in the sidebar of our main site. As an ad, it's very bad because it does not indicate at all what the target of the link is. A programming school? A museum? A philosophy board? ...

Comment: @Raphael a simple hover over with a mouse says **CS stackexchange chat room** and its already gotten a lot of hits, possibly even a higher rate than other ads... maybe despite the incessant pessimism, to quote you in chat its actually going _better than you feared_... still eagerly awaiting your own utterly flawless alternative!

Comment: This ad makes no sense to me. Turing had little to do with coding, in the sense that the word is used today (programming, not encrypting). The image has nothing to do with the concept of "chat". And coding has nothing to do with CS Stack Exchange. So what's going on here?

Comment: various/ several respondents on this thread seem not very historically aware. Turing helped design/ build/ "program" one of the 1st computers the so-called Bombe. the idea of whether coding is intrinsic to CS or not is a debated/ controversial statement in the field with expert/ elite proponents of each opposing view. the ad does _not seek to resolve it in only a few words._ still awaiting a superior alternative from all the _unimaginative/ narrowminded naysayers/ critics/ **PARTYPOOPERS**_ who dont really participate much in [chat] anyway, and apparently have zero interest in building it up!

Comment: Please. You say we're not historically aware but you claim that Turing "programmed" the bombe? The bombe was not a programmable computer. Also, referring to people who disagree with your as boldface-italics-shoutycaps-partypoopers isn't the most constructive remark you could make and nor is it the best way of getting people onto your side.

Comment: DR ah so are you against parties or not? there is _no question_ Turing was one of the original ***programmers/ coders*** _by any reasonable interpretation._ the Bombe had unmistakable elements of programmability/ ***("de-")coding***. apparently this ***basic fact*** is not taught in modern CS indoctrination classes for some reason...? maybe basic historical origins of CS are being effectively airbrushed away by omission in favor of some kind of distorted ideological agenda? since nobody has noticed in their partiality, the ***coding*** reference is also an allusion to ***cryptography***....

Comment: DW the opposition to the idea/ work seems to some degree to be inescapably related to personal characteristics of the opponents. if the shoe fits wear it. nobody in particular was named. _think that deleting comments esp on meta inhibits the free exchange of different povs/ opinions (as is being expressly_ invited/ encouraged _by a chat ad), bleaches the site of any color & that the opposition to the idea itself is not "nice"._ eg some perfectionism demanded by some incl mods :( ... if anyones self esteem is harmed by contemplation of the word "partypooper" perhaps they should avoid cyberspace

Comment: EJS thx for your support but _there are few real communities where "everyone is happy"_. my question is _why is the community unhappy?_ are you the self-appointed leader/ speaker/ representative for it? what exactly is this _team_ you speak of? what _teamwork_ are you referring to? isnt this particular instance an example of _high-resistance/ friction for something rather simple?_ is there really any teamwork going on this site, and if so, what is it capable of, what are its limitations? _the chat ad makes the community grow!_ ... alas it is easily shot down by others with no alternative! :(

Comment: @vzn " the Bombe had unmistakable elements of programmability/ ("de-")coding." No it didn't. It was a single-purpose machine. "apparently this basic fact is not taught in modern CS indoctrination classes for some reason...?" Er, because it's not actually true?

Comment: DR the modern idea of _"programmability"_ has evolved over many decades. words have changed meanings. CS is somewhat like psychology in that it has appropriated standard english terms/ words in technical/ specialized ways. all serious historical study must acknowledge this and avoid the trap of "moving the goalposts". old documents/ authors referred to the _programmability_ of ("precursor") machines that would not be viewed as "general purpose" from todays "retrospective lens". there is some challenge in aprising the past in an unbiased way. anyway read Turing 1936 for ***"real programming"***

Comment: _(fyi my prior comment to EJS refers to his now-deleted comment(s) about "making everyone in the community happy" etc)_ ... suggest further discussion be directed to the chat room

Comment: @vzn Wouldn't *"I compute, therefore I am."* make much more sense and also nicely allude to the Turing test and the possibility that the *I* in the sentence means an (intelligent) *machine* making the statement?

Comment: GWR nearly all the other proposed caption ideas are acceptable to me but dont feel like rewriting them myself. think others are overthinking this & being overly oppositional. marketing is not the same/ different than science! this is the 1st user-contributed custom ad in the history of this site. maybe dont set the bar so high? ps for all the ***ideological/ abstract/ theoretician/ hairsplitting purists,*** consider ***pseudocode*** is ***code***! and how many advanced (T)CS papers contain pseudocode? ad is performing very well as far as hits/ day. dont see compelling reason to further tinker.

Comment: Since there is a [preferred ad for chat](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1288/98), I vote to retract this one.

Comment: @Raphael Strongly agree.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 6):

[image: cryptography.stackexchange.com]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Support the proposal for a CS education SE site!]

Comment: Edit this for the new one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - done!

Answer (score 5):

[image: A curated list of answers that go over the basics in detail!]

Comment: For those concerned, the [photo is in the public domain](https://pixabay.com/en/pier-jetty-wooden-bridge-sea-1340589/).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch]

Comment: This userscript is a phenomenal (mostly-)one-man effort. [Ilmari Karonen](http://stackexchange.com/users/178805/ilmari-karonen) collects bug resports and feature/improvement requests from all over SE, including [our very own meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/537/missing-mathjax-in-the-duplicate-subtab-of-the-close-review-queue/817#817). As such, SOUP is a very useful thing to have installed.

Comment: If this meets with approval I'll recreate the thing in Inkscape, including suggestions, fixing alignments and restoring the "w" to its full glory.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Review queues]

Answer (score 3):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/cs.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://cs.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: Copied from http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884/8380; the size is *not* a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Computer Science Stack Exchange on Twitter]

Comment: An attempt to improve on [the beta default](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1196/98). Text up for discussion.

Comment: move the twitter logo right, then recenter. Compare it to the current twitter logo.

Comment: How about 'Stay Concurrent'?

Comment: @melchizedek Not bad! X-) Do we have a wordplay for the second clause, too? "Distribute" is maybe too obvious.

Comment: @Raphael I couldn't find a pun for the second clause, Distribute seems good enough. :)

Answer (score -2):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: I see, apparently the policy at least partially changed. Good luck collecting the upvotes.

Comment: what (part of?) policy change?

Comment: @vzn we had a discussion with Raphael about whether I am allowed to post this here or not and is remote sensing related to computer science or not?

Comment: I don't see any image here.  Did your link stop working?

Comment: @D.W. really?But there's no problem in my laptop or tablet even if I'm not logged in!

Comment: and the link works [image](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/90327.png)

Comment: Huh.  That's odd. I don't see any image.  It doesn't work for me.  I don't know why you can see it and I can't.  (The link to the Area 51 proposal works, but not the image.)

Comment: [The chat room dedicated to this proposal](http://goo.gl/VxYdsL)