# Are remote sensing and computer science related?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, meta

Regarding some programs in European and North American universities like:
[M.Sc. Remote Sensing and Computer Science in Aberystwyth, United Kingdom](https://www.mastersportal.com/search/master/computer-science-it)
[University of Colorado: Electrical, Computer and Energy engineering](https://ecee.colorado.edu/research/Prop_Remote_Sens.html)
I always thought that remote sensing, geoscience, gis and computer science are related topics.
I don't mean they are the same but I believe that their specialists should be able and are forced to work with each other.
For example my research as a remote sensing specialist involves data mining and pattern recognition and I should be able to write high performance code or hire someone that can write such code and run it on big data. A quick look at [my profile and my questions in different communities](http://stackexchange.com/users/1293467/sepideh) like game developement, stack overflow, code review, ... in recent years proves what I mean.
But I really don't understand why most of the people here disagree with this fact and don't let a [community promotion ad](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1198/34570) be shown in this site! I believe that there should be some remote sensing researchers who come to cs.se to solve their computer science ambiguities. I had a full discussion with [Raphael](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael) about it which was deleted and I also [showed him that I'm allowed to post an ad here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21708/142064).
I mean when [Robert Cartaino](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino) has let me to post the ad for a remote sensing and photogrammetry site on [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and he says:

> If the target sitea are running Community Promotion Ads (which these
> are), and the community is is **somewhat aligned** with subject of the
> site (which these seem to be), then yes; it is permitted to post your
> sample ad for consideration.

then let alone computer science which is a highly related topic to remote sensing. So why don't you agree with this ad be shown up on the side bar of the main site just sometimes?

Comment: oldtimers know its a difficult process starting new area51 proposals and most stall or even fail eventually :( ... unfortunately some of the history of these efforts is unavailable/ deleted... there is a lot of sentiments/ discussion of area51 in [chat] and one mod described it as something like a "disaster area"... you can also find a lot of opinions leaning toward stricter/ academic/ narrower interpretation of CS on this site rather than more encompassing... anyway dont take opposition too personally, this is the ~1st year of _any_ community supported ads passing on this site... good luck...

Comment: @vzn thanks for your attention but one way to prevent a proposal from failing is to let it ads pass on other community sites. Because you probably know that in order to success in a proposal, we need experienced stack exchange users more than new ones. Because the new ones will be scared off by the site creation process easily as [this discussion](http://goo.gl/2c7joX) suggests. And I think [my proposal](http://goo.gl/ommor5) will eventually fail. Because whenever I create a [chat room](http://goo.gl/7YCn8a) about it, there's no attention and people who have followed so far are not interested

Comment: to get involved with the proposal a lot. And because I'm from Iran (a third world country which has limited communication with other countries and is subject to online sanctions, I cannot boost my posts in facebook, linkein, twitter, etc because I cannot even pay the bills from within Iran. So there's not much advertisement about it and there's no foreign person who is interested in helping me to improve the remote sensing and photogrammetry community :(

Comment: Arguably, CS is related to (almost) *everything* nowadays in the sense that (almost) *everbody* uses CS artifacts in one way or the other. If for one don't even know what "remote sensing" is, and that after nine years in a CS department. Therefore, I don't think your proposal and CS are related enough for an ad -- but that's just my opinion. More generally, I think a field X and CS are related enough if results from X have influenced up-/mainstream CS.

Comment: Neither of the courses you link seems to contain any CS, at least not in the form of dedicated courses.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not sure. I'm just asking. As an M.Sc student in Iran, I've just entered the field of remote sensing (I have studied Geomatics Engineering for my B.E) and I see that we need concepts like pattern recognition, data mining, fuzzy theory, etc in our research topics that I think are computer science topics. So I feel a lot of gap in my computer science knowledge and don't know how to feel this gap.

Comment: @sepideh It certainly sounds as if remote sensing (can) involve(s) techniques from certain subfields of CS.  That doesn't mean that there's a general connectin/interest in the *other* direction. In particular, as long as you only *use* these concepts but do not expand upon the existing work in a way that interestes CSists, I don't think there would be such a connection. Similarly, we would not host economics ads (or so I'd think) even though economy students learn about e.g. Dijkstra's algorithm in their studies.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's seems to be some confusion or misunderstanding.  You're not being prevented from submitting a proposed community promotion ad.  In fact, you did submit such an ad, and it is up and available for voting.  You haven't been prevented at all.

As far as your complaints that Raphael has not let you post such an ad: those complaints seem unjustified.  Raphael initially had the impression that such ads were not allowed, but when you provided a reference, [Raphael wrote](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/community-promotion-ads-2016/1198#comment3774_1198):

> I see, apparently the policy at least partially changed. Good luck collecting the upvotes.

So you got what you wanted.

The reason the older comments were deleted is because they're no longer relevant, now that it's been made clear that such ad proposals are allowed here.

---

Right now, you have posted a proposed community promotion ad.  The way this works is that the *community* votes on each proposed ad, based on whether they think it should receive a slot as a community promotion ad.  In this case, your proposed ad has apparently not been very popular: it's currently at -2 (+1 upvote, -3 downvotes).  This is up to the community, not moderators.

Each community member is free to vote using whatever criteria they like.  They don't have to justify their votes.

If you would like to try to change people's minds, feel free to make the case: present the argument why an ad for the remote sensing Area 51 proposal would benefit this community.  Generally, community promotion ads tend to be used to try to benefit this site and this community.